# Embedd iOS Simulator in mac app

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Is it possible to embedd/integrate an iOS Simulator in a mac app?

I know it is possible to get an iOS app as a standalone app using iOS Simulator. 
https://github.com/stepanhruda/ios-simulator-app-installer

Our goal: Create a mac app with a text editor which displays the result in an iOS Simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible without a lot of reverse engineering on your part of things that I guarantee will likely change in subsequent releases.

You're probably better off trying to hack up an OSX WebKit.framework to behave the way you want and embed a web view from that.

Comment: I see. I need to render the result with UIKit, not HTML/Webkit.

Comment: Ah, my mistake then.  Your mockup looked like a webview.  In that case, you're pretty much out of luck.